# what kind of post-processing can be applied to obtain the most similar segmentation to ground truth?

Tags: image-processing, post-processing, connected-components, mathematical-morphology

I have applied my algorithm and the output of segmentation is the left image as follows:

[segmentation output(left), ground truth (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPTYF.png)

I have to do post-processing to the left image, to increase the similarity to the ground truth (right figure). My question is what kind of post-processing can be applied on the left figure? what kind of morphological operators and which structure element can be used to this aim? I tried some of them, but quite confusing. Can you please help me? or is there any function or code that I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be possible to post-process this image with mathematical morphology in order to get the result you wish for the simple and good reason that the top left part is completely merged with the pattern you want, and it is also the case for the bottom right pattern. So you have to work on the pre-processing in order to improve the result.

The best thing you can do in this case, would be:

1. Erosion in order to separate the pattern you want with the bottom right pattern.
2. Label the connected components.
3. Keep only the biggest component.
4. Dilation of the same size than the erosion, in order to find back something close to the original pattern.

It would be great to see the original image.